# How do I use my own coordinates instead of wParam? (using winapi)

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn

This is the overall code bellow:

```
LRESULT WmPointerAPI::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
HRESULT hr;
POINTER_INFO pointerInfo = {};

UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hr);

switch (message)
{
case WM_POINTERDOWN:
    // Get frame id from current message
    if (GetPointerInfo(GET_POINTERID_WPARAM(wParam), &pointerInfo))
    {
```

I'm focusing on:

```
if (GetPointerInfo(GET_POINTERID_WPARAM(wParam), &pointerInfo))
```

I'm currently using Leap Motion technology, which is a 3D sensor to plug coordinates into my application.
The problem is, I don't know how to plug my own "coordinates" into the wParam, so that it takes in my coordinates, rather then from cursor/touch screen.

How would I inject or simulate touch through wParam, using my own on screen coordinates?

Comment: `wParam` doesn't contain any coordinates, just the ID of the device that registered a touch. `GetPointerInfo` then queries the device for coordinates and other information. If you don't want to have the actual device fill `POINTER_INFO`, then fill it yourself with whatever values you want.

Comment: You cannot teach the pointer device new tricks, you will have to scale to world coordinates yourself.  This isn't very difficult, just a multiplication.  Beware of high DPI devices (larger than 120 dots per inch) and not declaring your app DPI-aware.  Your graphics output is scaled but the pointer is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### lParam

The coordinates are in the `lParam`, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454923.aspx):

```
Use the following macros to retrieve the physical screen coordinates of the point: 
* GET_X_LPARAM(lParam): the x (horizontal point) coordinate. 
* GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam): the y (vertical point) coordinate.
```

You can create a new `lParam` value using the [`MAKELPARAM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632661.aspx) macro. Example:

```
WORD screenX = 345; 
WORD screenY = 234;
LPARAM testLParam = MAKELPARAM(screenX, screenY);
```

### wParam

If you also want to create a `wParam`, then you should reverse-engineer which bits of `wParam` are read by the macros listed [in its description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454923.aspx), and create your own `wParam` value using bit operations. For example, [GET_POINTERID_WPARAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454893.aspx) reads the low-order `WORD` of `wParam`. The macro [MAKEWPARAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632664.aspx) can come in handy, too.